Minimize the dominating points
Given a set of n points in 3d space and an integer k, it is NP-hard to select k points from the skyline to maximize the number of points dominated by them. Is it still NP-hard to select k points form the skyline to minimize the number of points dominated by them?

This question needs some context. What is a “skyline”? What does it mean to “dominate”?

A point t is said to dominate another point s, if for each i, t[i] is less then s[i]. The skyline of a set of points is the set of points that are not dominated by any other point.
